# ogr2ogr - mapinfo to geojson. Merging shapes with certain values

Tags: geojson, mapinfo, ogr2ogr

I'm just starting out with this so apologies if I explain things poorly.

I have some mapinfo files (TAB, IND, MAP etc) and I am trying to convert to Geojson.  I can do this using ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" 1800-indoor.geojson coverage_LTE1800_Indoor.TAB
```

however the geojson is very large.  Actually however there is a lot of information in the mapinfo file (and thus the geojson file) that I don't actually require.  The random example tile of the map is below. Although it may not be apparent there are 5 'levels' of information ranging from 0 - 4.  [image: Example png from existing conversion process]

When I convert the file all that is important is that I preserve the shapes that have a 0 value (although looking in the mapinfo file these values don't seem to be explicit, presumably they are encoded somehow?) but the shapes representing values 1,2,3, and 4 can all be merged together.  Visually therefore I would end up with two colours, one that represents 0 and another which represents 1,2,3 and 4 combined.

EDIT - more info added in response to comment:

list of files

[image: List of files]

example of data in data.map file

```
000a 0e15 0e16 1ba2 a6ab 1a2a 2fa5 a9b5
a7b5 d90f 1723 131f 2b0f 1723 4f57 639c
a4a9 a0a8 ada4 a8ad 161a 390d 1137 a5a9
b5a4 a8ad b2b6 dcbd bdf4 2b2f 55c8 ccd8
c7cb d0d3 d7fd c2c2 f900 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: Is this vector data (ie polygons) or a raster/grid? The solution very much relies on the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @T_Bacon.  I've added some info to the question above.  I believe them to be standard MapInfo files which I think are grid rather than vector?

Comment: It looks like it's vector data given the file structure you've shown. Do you have MapInfo (or some other GIS) available to you? If so you will want to start by taking a look at the attribute information available to you and see if there's a field that defines the 'values' (ie 0-4).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have MapInfo or anything similar.  We receive the files as they are and don't have any specific software.  Looking in the data.tab file there is some information                                                                   Definition Table
  Type NATIVE Charset "Neutral"
  Fields 2
    Float Float ;
    String Char (32) ;
begin_metadata
"\IsReadOnly" = "FALSE"
"\MapInfo" = ""
"\MapInfo\TableID" = "6097d126-e41f-4f23-9d69-b3ea2c75ed4f"
end_metadata